# Choosing the right FET to switch between two sources

Tags: mosfet

The circuit below is based on the answer to this  [question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96059/switch-between-battery-and-usb-power-no-microcontroller-circuit), which i find to be suitable for my application.

3.3VDC is the main supply for the circuit, with 3.6V 1/2AA battery for backup, as defined by the product requirement. The load is basically three switches which should be powered by the main supply until there is an outage, in which case the battery takes over.

In seletcting the Diode, i picked the panasonic [DB3X313N](https://www.google.com.ng/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiwkdnr0rbOAhXGrY8KHWKmA8IQFgggMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.semicon.panasonic.co.jp%2Fds4%2FDB3X313N_E.pdf&usg=AFQjCNG2YzGNNkEszlFUu5uMKk8rqiqTVQ&sig2=UOeBkR-eCqzBrwE_gMTskg) with a Vf of 0.55V, this will drope the 3.3V supply to 2.75V which will still work, as the logic input will detect a high.

For the FET, I choose [Infineon-BSS84P-DS](https://www.google.com.ng/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi_zYWl0bbOAhWKPo8KHXZXB0oQFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.infineon.com%2Fdgdl%2FInfineon-BSS84P-DS-v02_07-en.pdf%3FfileId%3Ddb3a304330f68606013118ac7a9b4549&usg=AFQjCNGbptfO2pzIMttDB4DrgHSdrmgtVQ&sig2=4lcaAe7KNunuvLoK7DqmtA) , with a Vgs(th) of 1-2V.

The load is basically three switches with 10k pull up resistors, so the currrent draw is minimal.

I would like to ask:

1. Will this circuit function as expected, i.e. to supply the load from the 3.3V source and only source from the 3.6V battery when the mains source is unavailable.
2. If so, then is my choice of diode and FET suitable for this circuit, expecially with the FET, as i've not worked with FETs before.

[image: Source switching circuit]

Comment: What was the reason for choosing the FET? What is the maximum input voltage from the Battery

Comment: @Umar I choose the FET because the battery voltage (which is 3.6V) is higher than the main source voltage which is 3.3V. Without it, the battery will be the one feeding the circuit by default rather than the 3.3V source.

Comment: Right. the Gate source voltage of the FET at room temperature is -2 V maximum. So, should be fine. The reverse current of chosen diode is in 10 uA range. If the voltage after the diode drop is acceptable, the option is okay. What is the load current expected from the battery?

Comment: "Will this circuit function as expected?" - what are your expectations?

Comment: @Andyaka to supply power to the load via 3.3V as long as it is available, and only source from the 3.6v battery backup when the main source is not available.

Comment: What is the load current?

Comment: @PeterSmith the load current is less than 10mA

Comment: Forward voltage drop will not be 0.55V. Just look to datasheet. At 25°C and 10mA it will be around 0.25V

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device you have chosen is not fully specified for \$R_{DS(on)}\$ below -4.5V

[image: BSS84P Rds on]

There is no guarantee that the device will turn on fully with 3.6V of bias, and even if it does then you can expect a relatively high value of \$R_{DS}\$ of the order of \$10 \Omega \ to \ 20 \Omega\$ which will give a voltage drop of 100mV to 200mV across the FET.

I would be more inclined to use a part that is fully specified for a lower \$V_{GS}\$ such as the [DMG3415U](http://www.diodes.com/catalog/P_Channel_8V_to_29V_105/DMG3415U_5641) or perhaps the [Si2323CDS](http://www.vishay.com/mosfets/list/product-65700/), both of which are fully characterised at 2.5V \$V_{GS}\$

[image: Si2323CDS Rds on]

Either of these parts is guaranteed to turn on at the 3.6V bias you have with low on resistance; many others exist and these are simply suggestions.

Basically, look for devices specified for \$R_{DS(ON)} \$  preferably with \$R_{DS}\ \le 100m\Omega\$ at \$ V_{GS} \le\$ 2.5V