# How to detect charger connected to cut off battery and use externall power

Tags: power, mosfet, switching

I'm working on project which is supposed to be user friendly. It will usually run on battery and highest expected current draw is around 6A, but usually around 2A. I will probably use Li-On battery, perhaps 2 in series with equalizing and charging protection module.

I want to connect it via USB to PC for data transfer AND charging, or just power bank, or adapter only for charging.

As I am more programmer, than electrical engineer so I'm unable solve this problem. I need some sort of "power switch" which would be able to detect power from USB to charge battery and cut off battery output not to feed power back to USB and charger.

I thought about connecting the LED strip directly to discharge port - that would eliminate one branch of this problem. But there still remains the problem of switching Arduino power from battery to USB.

I found [Adafruit charger](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2465#technical-details) which seems to solve this problem, however its rated only up to 1A.
So I need that, but for up to 6A.

When searching around the internet I came across MOSFET in P channel configuration. If I understand them well they should basicaly "switch off" when they get voltage on Gate.

If this is a good way to think could you please help me how should I connect it all up?

If it's not the right way please point me in better direction.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switch between battery and USB power](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/21570/switch-between-battery-and-usb-power)

Comment: there's so many questions about "switch between USB and battery power here" that I had a harder time picking one than finding a dozen...

Comment: @MarcusMüller Partially yes. But as I said I'm not very good at electronics so I would appreciate some help with correct values. In your link - would the second picture with FET and schottky be enough? What values should I choose?